# player.position.x not defiend but object move, why is there an error?

Tags: javascript, three.js

```
var player;
//baut die objecte
buildobj = function () {
    // instantiate the loader
    loader = new OBJLoader2();

    // function called on successful load
    function callbackOnLoad(playership) {
        player = playership;
        playership.position.set(-7300, -7500, -1);
        playership.rotation.set(Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / -2, 0);
        scene.add(playership);
    }
    // load a resource from provided URL synchronously
    loader.load('AmerWarship.obj', callbackOnLoad, null, null, null);
}

//gameprocess
update = function () {
    player.position.x += 1;//error here
};
render = function () {
    //player.position.x += 1;
    renderer.clear();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
GameLoop = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {

        requestAnimationFrame(GameLoop);

    }, 1000 / 60);
    render();
    update();
    steuerung_tastatur_camera();

};
init(); //load init first!!
```

An error occurs when I try to update my object. But why? The object is declared as a player variable ? 
How can I fix the problem that I can access my object from anywhere ?

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined

Comment: You're not calling buildobj anywhere so the variable isn't defined as the object you are expecting

Comment: and how i can fix it ?

Comment: do I have to put the variable into the function and then return it ?

Comment: Technically since you've defined it as a global you can change it as you are doing now, but it seems that you're not running that function anyway (i.e. buildobj)? Also, what is init()? Where is that defined? In any case you need to make sure that you first load the data, and only then initiate any loops. Otherwise you'll get this error. So I'm guessing you will want "callbackOnLoad" to call a function which starts the loop.

Comment: Most likely because `update` is called before the object is loaded. Just wrap that code in an `if` statement like so: `if(player) { player.position.x += 1; }` so that it only accesses the player object if it is defined

Comment: it works many thanks :)

Comment: can i perhaps prevent the update from being executed before all objects are loaded ?

Comment: init = function () {
    //create scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    //create rendere
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    //rezize
    window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight;
        renderer.setSize(width, height);
        camera.aspect = width / height;
        camera.updateProjectmatrix;
    });
    //set and create camera

Comment: camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1500);
    camera.position.set(-7500, -8000, 500);
    camera.rotation.set(Math.PI / 4, 0, 0);
    //add light
    light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffbb, 0x080820, 1);
    light.position.set(0, 0, 1000)
    scene.add(light);
    //function build the mapp
    buildmapp();
    //function build the objs
    buildobj();
    //function starts the gameloop
    GameLoop();
}

Comment: @Florian then try [@Caharpuka's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58845384/player-position-x-not-defiend-but-object-move-why-is-there-an-error#comment103964556_58845384) which is the best approach by the way. You should start the game loop at the bottom of the function `callbackOnLoad`

Comment: thats my init function

Comment: I get it, first load all the objects and then I start the ini. So it works without error messages. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help :) BTW, don't use the code from my answer, calling `init` at the end of `callbackOnLoad` should do the job

Comment: I am really grateful for the help :) I tried to solve this alone for a week now :D I have almost no experience with Three js yet. Now i load first the objects , then starts the init which load the remaining things and then i start the gameloop